# Tracking state across recursive functions

Tags: php, recursion

I'm using a function I found on PHP.net that recursively examines a directory and its contents. It creates a nested array for each subdirectory where elements of those arrays correspond to filenames.

It doesn't keep track of filepaths. That's what I want. Here's the code:

```
function get_directory_tree( $outerDir, $filters = array() ){
  $dirs = array_diff( 
            scandir( $outerDir ), 
            array_merge( Array( ".", ".." ), $filters ) 
        );

  $dir_array = Array();

  foreach( $dirs as $d ){
    if(is_dir($outerDir."/".$d)){
        $dir_array[ $d ] = get_directory_tree( $outerDir."/".$d, $filters );
    } else {
        $dir_array[ $d ] = $d;
    }
  }
    return $dir_array;
  }
```

And it outputs this for my test case:

```
Array(
  [a] => Array(
        [aa] => Array(
                [hjkl.txt] => hjkl.txt
            )
        [asdf.txt] => asdf.txt
    )
  [b] => Array()
  [c] => Array()
 )
```

And this is what I would like it to output:

```
Array(
  [a] => Array(
        [aa] => Array(
                [hjkl.txt] => 'a/aa/hjkl.txt'
            )
        [asdf.txt] => 'a/asdf.txt'
    )
  [b] => Array()
  [c] => Array()
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change...

```
$dir_array[ $d ] = $d;
```

to...

```
$dir_array[ $d ] = $outerDir."/".$d;
```